# Windows 10 not detecting available updates

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

I'm using an old build of Windows 10 (Version 1511 Build 10586.753, found through winver). I haven't received any updates because I disabled Windows Update in services.msc a while back, but I've since re-enabled it and have tried updating Windows. Windows detected that there were available updates and downloaded them, but when it prompted me to restart my computer to install the updates, it kicked me out of the update at about 30% to the Windows login screen.

I tried restarting my computer to re-try the update, but nothing happened and I went straight to the login screen again. I went into Windows Updates to check for updates, but it's not detecting updates for some reason (I've ensured Windows Update in services.msc is enabled and running). I thought it might not be detecting any because the latest version was already downloaded, so I used Disk Cleanup to get rid of Windows installation files. I rebooted and checked Windows Update again, but it's still not detecting any updates.

My laptop, which was also upgrading from this same build, also could not install the update properly. I ended up re-imaging my laptop, and was able to update from that, but my desktop has a TB of programs that I'd need to back up or re-download, so I'd prefer not to wipe it. What can I try to update my desktop without re-imaging it?

Comment: Download the 1607 ISO, mount the ISO, install the feature update.  That's all you have to do.

Comment: Try using the Windows 10 Upgrade Assistent http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=823120